# MySQL subquery appears to be slowing down my main query, any tips on how to speed this up?

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery, query-optimization

I have a simple subquery in MySQL which produces a set of codes, something like 'LPR','LFR','LFL' (more codes can be returned).
Using this in my main query slows it right down, like it can take a minute or 2 to run.

I'm unable to show the full code, and there are over 2,000,000 rows in the `orders` table but, it's basically:

SubQuery:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT prefix 
 FROM `photo` 
 WHERE thedate BETWEEN '2024/02/10' AND '2024/02/20' 
   AND user = 'ABCD1')
```

MainQuery:

```
SELECT
field1,
field2
FROM `orders`
WHERE ((orders.buyers_date) BETWEEN '2024/02/01' AND '2024/02/29') AND orders.user = 'ABCD1' 
AND orders.prefix IN(
    (SELECT DISTINCT prefix FROM `photo` WHERE thedate BETWEEN '2024/02/10' AND '2024/02/20' AND user = 'ABCD1')
)
```

If within the MainQuery I replace the `IN` with the codes directly, as in

```
SELECT
field1,
field2
WHERE ((buyers_date) BETWEEN '2024/02/01' AND '2024/02/29') AND orders.user = 'ABCD1' 
AND orders.prefix IN('LPR','LFR','LFL')
```

The query takes around 6 seconds. I thought the subquery would have run first, then the main query. This doesn't seem to be the case.

I did try :

```
SET @prefs = (SELECT DISTINCT prefix FROM `photo` WHERE thedate BETWEEN '2024/02/10' AND '2024/02/20' AND user = 'ABCD1')

SELECT @prefs;
```

The result is "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)", it's Lying!

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you storing your dates as VARCHARs instead of DATEs? What indices do you have on these two tables? Adding full DDL for both tables and EXPLAIN output would help.

Comment: VARCHARs were there initially. I could change that to datetime. AlI can give for `Explain` is (main query) ref=const, rows=275544, Extra="Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort". thanks.

Comment: If you cannot share DDL and EXPLAIN for full query then there's not much we can suggest beyond Akina's answer.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE orders; and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE photo;  so we can see what the system optimizer has to deal with to select data for your use.  The EXPLAIN would be nice using the complete MAIN query but if you can not do that, we will do the best we can for you in terms of suggestions which will have multiple columns to be indexed for selections.

Comment: What is the 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question? Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments; delete & flag obsolete comments.

Answer (score 1):

Use WHERE EXISTS:

```
SELECT field1, field2
FROM orders
WHERE orders.buyers_date BETWEEN '2024/02/01' AND '2024/02/29'
  AND orders.user = 'ABCD1' 
  AND EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM photo
               WHERE photo.thedate BETWEEN '2024/02/10' AND '2024/02/20' 
                 AND photo.user = 'ABCD1'
                 AND orders.prefix = photo.prefix
               );
```

PS. Your date literals have wrong format (from MySQL looking point) - do you use VARCHAR datatype instead of DATE?

Comment: Yes I do, I use varchar(25).

Answer (score 0):

Add these indexes -- The order of the columns in these composite orders is important:

```
photo:   INDEX(user, theDate, prefix)
orders:  INDEX(user, prefix, buyers_date)
orders:  INDEX(prefix, user, buyers_date)
```

`IN ( SELECT ... )` is rarely optimal.

This *may* be the best way to structure your query:

```
SELECT  o.field1, o.field2
    FROM  ( SELECT  DISTINCT prefix
                FROM  `photo`
                WHERE  thedate BETWEEN '2024/02/10' AND '2024/02/20'
                  AND  user = 'ABCD1') 
          ) AS p
    JOIN `orders` AS o  ON o.prefix = p.prefix
    WHERE  o.buyers_date BETWEEN '2024/02/01' AND '2024/02/29'
      AND  orders.user = 'ABCD1'
```

(I don't know which of my recommendations for index for `orders` is better.  By having both, the Optimizer will pick the one it thinks is better.  The choice *may* depend on the distribution of the data, so it may change.  See `EXPLAIN SELECT...`)

Also, I don't know whether Akina's suggestion will be better.  But his formulation needs:

```
photo:   INDEX(user, prefix, theDate)
orders:  INDEX(user, buyers_date, prefix)
```